# Using Identify tool on rasters to find min/max values in ArcMap

Tags: arcgis-desktop, raster, arcmap, identify

When you use the Identify tool in ArcMap 10.8.2 to select an area on a raster, you only get the value from the starting corner.

Is it possible somehow to instead get max/min values, or even more advanced stuff like mean/medians?

Answer (score 1):

The identify tool returns the value of the pixel (the point location you clicked on), so there is no min or max for a single pixel value. Such statistics can be created for an *area*. You need to create your areas as polygons in a Feature Class then you can use the zonal statistics tool.

Comment: The identify tool can be held and dragged to identify from an area. This works as expected for vectors where you get info from all objects partially within the dragged area. I don't see why this couldn't somehow work similarly for a raster?

Answer (score 0):

If you are interested only in the raster's statistics, these are available in the metadata if you have calculated statistics for the raster. There are geoprocessing tools to do this and to build pyramids; creating statistics and pyramids is useful for rasters you will be using regularly. You need values such as min-max to symbolize your raster data. Pyramids make the rasters draw faster as you zoom in, out, and around your data. I do this with new imagery from outside providers.

If you are interested in sections of the raster, look into creating summary rasters with statistics using Raster Algebra, or as mentioned already, creating polygons and using vector tools such as Zonal Statistics or stretched symbology.